# Where is RewriteMap allowed?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

This seems like a very simple question.

I tried putting a RewriteMap directive in an .htaccess file but the logs showed an alert:

```
RewriteMap not allowed here
```

Then I tried putting it in the VirtualHost declaration in the apache2/sites-available file, but reloading apache gives me:

```
RewriteMap not allowed here
...fail!
```

In both cases with RewriteEngine on.

Is this referring to the location of the actual map on the file system, or the RewriteMap directive?

Just in case it helps:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  etc...
  <Directory /var/www/site>
  AllowOverride all
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteMap map txt:/var/www/site/map.txt
  RewriteRule /path/[^/]+/([^/]+) ${map:$1} 
  etc...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) it's only allowed in the scope (Context: in the infobox) of server config, virtual host. Place it outside the [directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) and it will work.

Comment: works perfect!!!